# CloudCannon automatic builds not running on specified date and time

Tags: jekyll, cloudcannon

I'm attempting to use CloudCannon's [Automatic Build](https://cloudcannon.com/documentation/build/scheduling/#automatic-builds) to schedule posts. I've created a `_schedule.txt` file in the root of my project and added the file in my `include` inside of my `_config.yml` per their documentation. I've tried several times but can't get it to work. What am I missing?

**_schedule.txt**

```
2021-06-15T13:00:00+00:00:00,guestpost,_posts/2021-06-15-the-greatest-guest-post-ever.md
```

**_config.yml**

```
include: ["_schedule.txt"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working using your example but removing the last `:00` from the date on the `_schedule.txt` file.

```
2021-06-15T13:00:00+00:00:00 // Doesn't work
2021-06-15T13:00:00+00:00    // Works
```

My files:

**_schedule.txt**

```
2021-10-29T13:00:00+00:00,guestpost,_posts/2021-10-29-the-greatest-guest-post-ever.md
```

**_config.yml**

```
include: ["_schedule.txt"]
```